# Laravel 5 Auth Register After Login

Tags: laravel, authentication

I am trying to create users after login in Laravel 5. Register route is

```
get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
```

It should be accessible with or without login as I have not used any middleware in it. But when I try to navigate to auth/register if logged in then It redirects me to /home. I can only access it before login.

How can I make it accessible after login?

Comment: actually there is a middleware applied to it in the scaffolding. hmmm I get your pain trying to find docs on what exactly is in the scaffolding so we can edit them

Comment: Can you please give somemore detail about it?

Comment: enter the artisan command route:list then you will see register route has a middleware assigned to it.

Comment: yes got it...but how can remove it?

Comment: if you want to make a page where you can add users, dont do it in the registration page. make another page for it.

Comment: thanks gokigoooks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The middleware is set in the `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php` class constructor.

If your using Laravels boilerplate authentication controller, it will probably look something like this:

```
class AuthController extends Controller 
{

    ...

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }

    ...

}
```

You could remove the `$this->middleware()` line entirely to prevent the middleware being applied to all your login and register routes.

Alternatively you could add any route exceptions to the array passed as the second parameter to prevent the middleware being applied to just those methods.

```
$this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['getLogout', 'getRegister', 'postRegister']]);
```

Comment: that middleware is there for a reason. dont you think? I think hes trying to add users even when logged in, so why not make an AddUsers page for it?

Comment: The question was to allow the boilerplate authentication routes to be accessible to both logged in and logged out users. This is how you achieve it. The middleware is there for a reason, but if your apps usecase doesn't fit into Laravels **boilerplate** authentication, then you should extend/change it to suit your needs.

Comment: Then please give him insight in how to extend the boilerplate to suit his needs. Not give him advices leading to bad design.

Comment: How is this bad design?

Comment: registered users can also register again? maybe we should ask what hes trying to achieve. maybe hes making an add user functionality.

Comment: What he is trying to achieve is secondary to his question. Stack Overflow is not a place to discuss application design, it's for getting help with specific programming problems. As OP doesn't state anything about his intentions, I'm going to assume he knows exactly what he's doing.

Comment: Wow. Its just like your saying stackover flow is a place where spoiled kids get what they want. I wasnt even talking about design. I was talking about good practice in general. And stackoverflow isnt a place for bad practice. if you want easy points then this is not your place

Comment: Tell me exactly what is bad practice about my answer?

Comment: thanks Jeemusu...I got the concept...thanks to Gokigooooks for explaining me that this is not a good practice...

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply comment the line.

```
public function __construct(Guard $auth, Registrar $registrar)
{
    $this->auth = $auth;
    $this->registrar = $registrar;

    //$this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout', 'getRegister', 'postRegister']);
}
```