# How to put /register behind user login in laravel auth scaffold

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

I have used laravel auth scaffold in laravel 5.2

With this, I am able to access '/register' perfectly. Now, I am trying to put '/register' behind user login. Meaning, a user should be able to access '/register' only if it has logged-in else it should redirect to '/login' page.

NOTE: I have already created few users, so there is nothing to worry that how a user can login without registering as I am already having few users and that are the only one I need.

Can anyone help me in this please!

Answer (score 1):

I am able to get this done. Here's the way I followed:

In **routes.php**, add these lines:

```
Route::auth();    //already there after laravel auth scaffold
Route::group(array('middleware' => 'auth'), function () {
    Route::get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
    Route::post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@register');
});
```

**app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php**
Change from:

```
$this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
```

to:

```
$this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => ['logout', 'showRegistrationForm', 'register']]);
```

And now, whenever I try to access **/register** without logging-in as some existing user, it redirects me to **/login** page. And if I logs-in and try to access **/register** page, it shows me register page as I want it to have.
Reference: [Laravel 5 Auth Register After Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514713/laravel-5-auth-register-after-login)